# Combining separate logistic regressions for a roll rate model

Tags: regression, logistic

I would like to model roll rates. At each period, an item with status S_i can roll into N possible status next period S_1, S_2, ..., S_N  where those N statuses are mutually exclusive

I don't want to use multinomial logit. Instead, I would like to model multiple separate logit models

P(S_1=1), P(S_2=1)... P(S_(N-1)=1)

and assume P(S_N) will just be a residual probability

When model separately, P(S_1=1) predicted value matches exactly with actual P(S_1=1) and so on
But now, I need to combine them into one single model to make sure P(S1=1)+P(S2=1)+...P(S_N=1) sums up to 1

So for each status, I compute exp(XB)=P/(1-P), such that the probability now becomes

P(S1=1) = exp(X1B1)/sum(1+exp(X1B1)...+exp(X_(N-1)*B_(N-1))

...

P(S_N=1) = 1/sum(1+exp(X1B1)...+exp(X_(N-1)*B_(N-1))

Even though the sum of all probs is now 1, the predicted P(S1=1) no longer match with actual P(S1=1) and so on.

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: How wrong is *wrong*? Off by a few decimal places? Or really off? Why don't you show some actual values wrt how you summed them up to conclude it was *wrong*?